# How can I only allow whitelisted queries with Graphene?

Tags: python, graphene-python

Looking at Graphene to provide a public API, if you were to naively follow the documented examples, it would be relatively easy to provide an API that would be vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks, even if they aren't intentional:

- Unpaginated queries could return too much data.
- Overly deep queries, perhaps even circular queries, could lead to far too many joins on your database.

For that reason, I'm inclined to say that the simplest approach to protecting a public GraphQL API is to have a whitelist of queries in production. If the query isn't in the whitelist, and the user isn't an admin, deny the query.

So, that begs the question: How would one maintain a whitelist of queries in Graphene and reject queries not on that whitelist? Some ideas:

- A WSGI middleware on top of Graphene: This is problematic because it would involve parsing the gql query to decide whether it's really whitelisted. That's Graphene's job, so it's a non-starter.
- A Graphene middleware. This is still too granular; Graphene's middleware doesn't seem to run once per query, but rather, once per *node on a query*. So that's not a good solution either.

So, without trying to dig into monkey-patching Graphene, I'm left with the same question: How do I implement a query whitelist with Graphene? (Or, alternatively, how should I protect a production Graphene server from overly expensive queries?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphene middleware is actually what I would (and I do) use for such requirement. It is granular, but for a reason - whole GraphQL was designed with granularity in mind. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by running *once per query*. Query fields are what matters and if you mean you want to whitelist top-level fields, middleware is perfectly suitable for that. This practise is also indirectly suggested in [Serving over HTTP](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) - you leave the authentication to the HTTP layer (e.g. using JWT) and authorization to the GraphQL middleware. This is also one of the usage examples from [Graphene documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/middleware/#example).